# How to route non-ascii URLs in Flask python

Tags: python, flask, utf-8, pycharm, non-ascii-characters

Good afternoon, everyone!

I have a problem with the routing my URL adress to Flask, precisely with running it in web-browser. All I want is to transfer the sharp symbol "#" and some Russian words (as like "**#привет**" or "**#ПомогитеМнеПожалуйста**") together.

The screenshot of error:
[image]

My programming code at the moment looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hashtags/' + b'<names>'.decode('utf-8'), methods=['GET'])
def get_hashtags(names):
    return jsonify({'Segmentation Hashtags': names})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=9876)
```

So, basically, `<names>` is a parameter from function `get_hashtag` that is used for transfering my future hashtag to the web-browser using `jsonify`. 
I need to find the way of transfering any hashtag I want with sharp symbol "#" plus Russian letters. As far as I know, there is an ASCII-coding methods, but I have no idea how to use it properly. 
**And `<names>` have structure: "#привет"**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `%23` instead of `#`, because the hash symbol marks a fragment in a URL. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax)

So the actual URL `app.route` is getting is `/hashtag/`

It seems to be impossible to get the content after `#`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752995/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to decode your url before passing it to your view methods, this way:

```
@app.route('/hashtags/<names>'.encode('utf-8'), methods=['GET'])
```

Comment: I have error:  @app.route('/hashtags/<names>'.decode('utf-8'), methods=['GET'])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: I tried this construction: @app.route('/hashtags/<names>'.encode('utf-8'), methods=['GET'])   and have a problem:  if not string.startswith('/'):
TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str

Comment: @ksusha, that is another issue, please update your question with it.

Comment: And that is probably, because you converted your string into bytes with `'/hashtags/<names>'.encode('utf-8')`, like I said update your question to work out a better solution.