# Flask URL route encoding problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, unicode, werkzeug

I stumbled upon a strange Unicode
URL encoding problem in Flask.

```
@app.route("/it2/<string:name>")
def render_it2(name=""):
    name = _fix_encoding(name)
    return _render_file("it2", name)
```

When `name` contains Unicode characters,
they are decoded as `iso-8859-1`
instead of `utf-8`.

So I had to add the `_fix_encoding` function:

```
def _fix_encoding(string):
    return string.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf8')
```

I understand that it is dirty hack,
that's why I would like to ask Flask/Werkzeug gurus,
what is wrong with my setup? What should I change in order to get URLs decoded in UTF-8 already, so that this ugly re-encoding would be not needed?

There are a lot of similar questions/answers on SO, but no responses that could be really helpful, e.g.:

- [How to route non-ascii URLs in Flask python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49847076/how-to-route-non-ascii-urls-in-flask-python)

I suppose that there should be some environment varialbe, or some configuration option that influences default Flask encoding.

I have the following `LANG`/`LC_*` on that host:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8

$ export | grep LC
declare -x LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
```

No `iso-8859-1` whatsoever. Where does it come from?

Comment: where is the code that yields the "name" that is used in the URL? As far is this part of the code is concerned, "name" is simply an input: it is created with the incorrect encoding elsewhere.

Comment: @jsbueno I don't really get your question. What code do you mean? It is a one-line Flask application; `import Flask` and this function, it is the whole code

Answer (score 0):

What application/code/web-page does create the URL in which "name" is embedded?

It is on the HTTP headers generated by that the place where "name" is already utf-8 encoded, but the HTTP side of your framework is being told it is latin1. You don't see that much because usually URLs are escaped with "%HH" - where "HH" are bytes in an UTF-8 sequence. If you can, change the source of your URLs to proper escape them (in Python, the call for that would be `urllib.parse.quote(url)`).

Check the official URL spec, from session 2.1 to 2.5 here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1

Apparently there is no standard way to tell the HTTP server components (on the Python side, the WSGI layer and Flask itself) which is the text-encoding of the URL itself - and these components are assuming Latin-1 (AKA iso-8859-1) for the bytes outside the ASCII set used by your utf-8 data.

And finally - if quoting the URL at the source is not an option, then your approach is good enough. You probably would be better guarding your `_fix_encoding` function against mal-formed utf-8 data, otherwiser your application will fail. (Simply adding an `errors="replace"` parameter in your call to `.decode` will do)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, in short it means: "it is ok, live with it". It is helpful at least from that point of view, that I don't feel myself too silly, because I missed something obvious. But I hope still, that there must be some real solution. At least, it worked properly before (python 2.x based). In a real-life scenario, there will be a web-frontend server anyway, which will be able to encode URL as we want it, but I wonder how I can configure Flask, so that it handles URLs properly on its own

Comment: The difference for Python 2.x is that Flask would handle the view a byte-string: your view would choose how to decode it. Now, Flask ahandles you a text string: it has to decode it first - but there is no way in the spec where the encoding of the URL is declared and Flask + WSGI assume latin-1. The advantage of this encoding is that it is "lossless" : all bytes in the URL will become a unicode character in the 0-256 range. Doing what you do can change it back to the proper encoding.  
Maybe there is some config that could be changed to flask deliver the url as bytes and not try to decode it

Comment: Yes I agree about the config, and actually that was my original question

Comment: Does anyone have any more information about a config fix for this? When I have a `\u2019` character in my URL, werkzeug throws me `UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character ... ordinal not in range(256)` from here: `return s.encode("latin1").decode(charset, errors)`