# Route Flask : Problem of space and accent in a route with variable

Tags: flask, encoding, routes

I created an application with Flask.

Locally, everything works.

But now that I have sent to the server, I have a routing problem.

The url that causes the problem is built like this:

```
@app.route('/analyze/<string:keyword>')
```

The problem is that the keyword variable can contain **accents** (éèàç, etc ...) and **spaces** (example : **sol stratifié**)

The problem is that instead of laminate floor, I have **sol%20stratifi%c3%a9** which appears on the screen, but also when I call the database.

**I tried**:

- encode and decode utf- 8 on the keyword variable : it doesn't work
- import codecs : it doesn't work
- test to use the function : [Flask URL route encoding problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64576519/flask-url-route-encoding-problems)
- try to add .encode('utf-8') directly in the url route

would you have a solution ?

Comment: `from urllib.parse import unquote; unquote( 'sol%20stratifi%c3%a9')` -> `'sol stratifié'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sol%20stratifi%c3%a9` is a [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) string (*URL quoted* or *`%xx` escaped* in Python terminology).

The [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/urllib.parse.html) module defines functions that fall into two broad categories: URL parsing and [URL quoting](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting).

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
print( unquote( 'sol%20stratifi%c3%a9'))
```

> ```
> sol stratifié
> ```