# flask didn't respond to me when I sent a request with html codes, but it did when I sent a request with plain text

Tags: html, flask, post, http-status-code-404

flask framework is throwing 404 error when i post request to content with html codes as data. But if I send a plain text in this request, it returns a response. why is it showing 404 error when I send request with html codes?
**Query result:**
[404 not fount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz5Mr.png) [result OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bnf0.png)

**flask code:**

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify, send_from_directory, render_template, redirect, request, session,url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/apix',methods=["POST","GET"])
def apix():    
    if request.form.get('test'):
        return "OK"
    else:
        return "NO"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=1000,debug=True)
```

ajax:

```
  let datax = {test:'<img width="500px" src="image.png">'}
  $.ajax( {
          url: '/apix',
          type: 'POST',
          data: datax,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false
        } ).done(function (data) {
            if (data=="OK"){
              alert("OK
            }
            else{
              alert('NO');
            }
            

        });
```

When I send html code to /apix it should accept and return "OK".

Answer (score 0):

Flask isn't great at dealing with special characters- I assume beginning your value with "<" is the issue. Perhaps [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752995/how-to-get-access-to-the-url-segments-after-a-in-python-flask) could help?

Comment: I checked, the ' " ' character in the html code is killing it. It also returns the data with the html code without the character. How can I solve this?

Comment: it works fine in windows operating system. after i moved it to hosting it is giving me this error.

Comment: Is there a reason you're confined to key:value pairing? Could you send the information as a json?

Comment: I have a data which consists of html codes and I want to send it to flask and process it. It doesn't matter if the data view is (json, html). I'm more interested in the error I get when I send data to flask with html code.